# Creating timer algorithm in php

Tags: php, algorithm, math, time

I'm working on an application that sends alerts to users via email. The user chooses a time-frame and sets up any number of alerts to receive in that time-frame.

The goal is to send the alerts at equal time intervals.

For example a user sets up 8 alerts for 12 hours (this repeats daily). I use simple division to determine at which time intervals to send the 8 alerts one-by-one. 12 hours/8 alerts = intervals of 1 hour and 30 minutes. The code should be executed every 1h30m for 8 times.

What PHP functions can I use to create this algorithm? Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be better served using `cron` or something similar.  PHP, by default, will stop running any script after 30 seconds.  If you're using a hosted web provider, this is often non-negotiable.

I will concede that some people write "console"-type applications that are run locally (e.g. via the command line), but since you didn't say you're doing this, I think we're safe to assume that is not the case.

One way of using `cron` would be:
Have the user specify the time interval and store it in a database.  Then at some other interval (perhaps every minute, or every 5 minutes) check the database to see whether the last time you sent an email is longer than the requested interval.  If it is, you would send another email and update the "last time sent" value in the database.

But having a PHP script "sleep", or even worse, get locked in an infinite while loop, is not a good use of the system's resources.

Comment: I agree that you will need cron. My script assumes you call it via cron every 5 minutes, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I think the logic in your example is a good outline of what one might put in the php script called by cron.

Comment: Thanks for the advice jedwards! I didn't know that any PHP script has a 30 seconds runtime. That's very troubling.. In my case there is a minimum 1 hour time interval for each user alert but multiple users will get alerts simultaneously.. so if alerts are being sent continually without pause the script will stop running at 30 seconds? Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: If you are using a default installation of PHP, yes, see the [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function and the [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) configuration option, both default to 30 seconds.  If the only times you could send emails to anyone is at the hour mark (1:00, 2:00, 3:00,...) it would be trivial to setup a cron job to "hit" the page where you determine which emails, if any, need to be sent.

Answer (score 2):

Off the cuff, here's the logic.  Unless I'm missing something it can be done by storing start time, end time, and last message in a database as a timestamp.

```
$start = 0;
$end = 12;
$number_msgs = 8;
$interval = ($end - $start)/$number_msgs;

$now = time();
$last_msg =  ; // last msg timestamp from db
if($now - $last_msg > $interval){
    //send email
}
```

The code above needs some adjustments to convert the interval (in hours above) to seconds (because `time()` is in seconds)

Hope this is useful.